# How to manually bootstrap AngularJS with Angular-UI (UI-Bootstrap) using RequireJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-ui

I know about this:

```
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']);
```

how to achieve the same with manual bootstrapping with something like this:

```
angular.bootstrap(document, ['myModule']);
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to do both.  `angular.module` is to declare/create the module, but it doesn't start "running" under you do the `angular.bootstrap` piece

Comment: Yes, that's right just recently figured it out. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you. One caveat is that you should load your JavaScript at the **bottom** of your index page. This is so that the bootstrap method is loaded after the document is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a best practice. I've encountered also some problems when manually trying to bootstrap angular. Sometimes it did work, other times it didn't. For example, I need some info from my backend before I can start angular.

So after my HTTP calls, I run this code:

```
angular.element(document).ready(function () {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myModule']);
});
```

I'm also using Angular-UI / UI-bootstrap and it works fine.